# Eigenvalue degeneracy

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quantum-mechanics

Excuse my notation, it carries from physics.

Suppose we have an operator $A$. The eigenvalue $\lambda$ is said to be $g$-fold degenerate if there exists *g* linearly independent eigenvectors with eigenvalue $\lambda$. So we can define the set of these linearly independent kets $\{|\psi\rangle\}_{i=1,...,g}$.

Furthermore, we can form a $g$-dimensional *eigensubspace* $\mathcal{E}$ from this set. Now, consider a ket $|\chi\rangle$ that lives in $\mathcal{E}$; then, we can express it as a linear combination of our set of kets such that
$$|\chi\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^g \alpha_i\ |\psi\rangle_i.$$

Now, 
$$A\ |\chi\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^g \alpha_i\ A\ |\psi\rangle_i=\lambda \sum_{i=1}^g \alpha_i\ |\psi\rangle_i=\lambda |\chi\rangle.$$

Thus, we see that $|\chi\rangle$ too has an eigenvalue of $\lambda$. In fact, we have infinite number of kets that can be written as a linear combination of the set $\{|\psi\rangle\}_{i=1,...,g}$.

So why isn't $\lambda$ *infinitely*-degenerate? From this argument, it seems that if $\lambda$ has degeneracy greater than 1, then it would be infinitely degenerate since we can write infinitely many kets that have the same eigenvalue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are indeed infinitely many eigenvectors, but not infinitely many **linearly independent** ones.  The dimension $g$ of the subspace is the largest possible number of linearly independent vectors in the subspace.

Comment: But if I can write infinitely many kets in the $g$ subspace with different coefficients, then they all are linearly independent. So I end up with infinitely many linearly independent kets! Just thinking in $xy$-plane, we have the basis $x$ and $y$ that are linearly independent; but then so are vectors $v_1=4x+7y$ and $v_2=5x+3y$. So can't we just make infinitely many linearly independent vectors from a finite dimension of basis?

Comment: Your confusion comes from somewhat unfortunate terminology.  Linear independence is a property of **sets** of vectors, but we speak of vectors being linearly independent.  When I write "the largest possible number of linearly independent vectors", it actually means "the largest possible number of vectors in a linearly independent set".